# holomorphic function writen as a serie

Tags: complex-analysis

To each complexe number $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ we associate a function defined by:
$$
f_\alpha(z)=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}z^n
$$
I want to show that this function is holomorphic on the unit disk; All I can remark is that the second term of the function is entire but what about the "1" is that makes $f_\alpha(z)$ a holomorphic function ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The second term - the infinite sum - is only entire when $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$. In general that series has finite radius of convergence (namely $1$).

Comment: Yes you're right, but can we still prove that $f_\alpha$ is holomorphic ?

Comment: Sure. Do you know that the sum function of a convergent power series is holomorphic on the disk of convergence?

Comment: Yes I know that, but what confuses me is that "1" there how can I get it in the sum ?

Comment: $1$ is holomorphic, so $f_{\alpha}(z)-1$ is holomorphic if and only if $f_{\alpha}(z)$ is.

Comment: You can get it into the sum as the case $n = 0$ of $$\Biggl(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha+1-k}{k}\Biggr)\cdot z^n,$$ or, shorter, $\binom{\alpha}{n}z^n$.

Comment: okay, that makes sense now. Thank you !

Comment: $f_a(z)=(1+z)^a.~$ See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).